# Error creating a Hive table in HDInsight from a different blob container: Path is not legal

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (Column1 string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

LOAD DATA INPATH 'asv://hivetest@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/foldername' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test1 ;
```

Loading the data generates the following error:

> FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:18 Path is not legal
>   ''asv://hivetest@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/foldername'':
>   Move from:
>   asv://hivetest@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/foldername to:
>   asv://hdi1@hdinsightstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/hive/warehouse/test1
>   is not valid. Please check that values for params "default.fs.name"
>   and "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" do not conflict.

The container `hivetest` is not my default HDInsight container. It is even located on a different storage account. However, the problem is probably not with the account credentials, as I have edited `core-site.xml` to include `mystorageaccount`.

How can I load data from a non-default container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's [impossible by design](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/22cf9a71-cce7-4765-a78e-2dc569d69a8a/hive-path-is-not-legal-azure-storage?forum=hdinsight) to load data into a Hive table from a non-default container. The workaround suggested by the answer in the link is using an external table.

I was trying to use a non-external table so I can take advantage of partitioning, but apparently it's possible to partition even an external table, as explained [here](http://blog.zhengdong.me/2012/02/22/hive-external-table-with-partitions).